# retrieve xml type string

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am using xml to linq but cannot find a way to retrieve the string "thing" in the following code:
    `<element type = "thing">`
here is my c# code

```
foreach (XElement q in xdoc.Descendants("question"))
        {
            name = #need syntax here to retrieve the type
            Console.WriteLine(name);
            text = q.Element("questiontext").Element("text").Value.ToString();
            if (name == "truefalse")
            {
                qList.Add(Question.makeType(name, text));
            }
        }
```

Comment: what is `name`? I will assume it is a `string`. So you want the object type of something as a string and assigned to `name`?

Comment: "Hi, I have some XML I refuse to show you. Can you tell me what's in it?" No.

Comment: the only xml needed to show was the <element type = "thing"> all i wanted was to know how to retrieve this type value. Your attitude was not necessary

Comment: I don't have a clue who you are, and people who refuse to provide more than the tiniest possible decontextualized snippets of information here are almost invariably hiding the actual problem.

Comment: I get your frustration, but as you can see my snippet of information was plenty to get the simple answer i was seeking. As this was not a bug issue, simply a search for knowledge which i had failed to find elsewhere. On top of that, is it really necessary to discourage new stackoverflow users with downvotes for not providing info exactly how you would like it even though it got the job done for them?

Comment: @Zannith, Stack Overflow is not here to "get the job done for them". It's to create a library, in effect, of high quality questions and answers. We therefore expect a certain level of effort to be taken when asking a question, which is outlined in [ask], and for questions about code, [mcve]. We are volunteers donating our time to answer questions. Asking you to do a little prep work seems reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should work to find all the "truefalse" type questions.

```
var questions = 
   from question in xDoc.Descendants("question")
   where question.Attribute("type").Equals("truefalse")
   select question;
```

Comment: Wow thanks for going beyond the question. That will actually work great for what i am trying to do. Sorry i cannot upvote due to being quite new.

Answer (score 0):

```
name = q.Attribute("type").Value;
```

Comment: Thank you, that gets it done. For some reason i could not find that anywhere with a simple google search.